# Non-split groups

Tags: reference-request, definitions, rt.representation-theory, gr.group-theory, examples

I am looking for a reference with definitions on what it means for an algebraic group to be split, quasi-split, and non-split. I would like to see some examples of the different "types".

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php?title=Split_group

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the basic definitions and examples, you will find a concise description of the vocabulary needed to talk about linear algebraic groups over fields that are not algebraically closed in T. A. Springer's article titled *Reductive Groups*, which appears in Part I of *Automorphic Forms, Representaions, and L-Functions* (Proceedings of a conference in Corvallis), A.Borel and W.Casselman (editors), AMS, 1979.

Comment: The entire thing used to be available online for free on the AMS website. This no longer seems to be the case. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 3):

As far as references go, you can look in pretty much any book on algebraic groups, like Borel or Humphreys or Platonov-Rapinchuk.

Here is a standard example: The norm torus of the extension $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}$ is the circle group, whose analytification is the compact Lie group $U(1)$.  It is not split, since it is not isomorphic to the multiplicative group (whose analytification is $\mathbb{R}^\times$).  It is quasi-split because all tori are quasi-split.

One example of a non-quasi-split group is $U_{2,\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}}$.  The compactness of the analytification obstructs the existence of a real Borel subgroup.